# Binary tree to general tree

Tags: data-structures

I know that from a general tree you can construct a **unique** binary tree, but is the reverse true? i.e can you get a **unique** general tree from a binary tree?

Comment: Yes you can interconvert Binary Tree and N-ary/General tree. Refer to the discussion forum here: https://leetcode.com/problems/encode-n-ary-tree-to-binary-tree/discuss

Comment: the above link is paywalled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The following transformation is reversible:

Given a general tree with **ordered but not indexed** children,
encode the first child as the left child of its parent, and each other node as a right child of its (former) sibling.

The reverse is:
Given a binary tree with **distinguished left and right children**, read the left child of a node as its first child and the right child as its next sibling.

So, the following tree

```
  a
 /|\
b c d
```

is encoded as

```
  a
 /
b
 \
  c
   \
    d
```

while the following tree

```
   a
  / \
 b   c
 |
 d
```

is encoded as

```
     a
    /
   b
  / \
 d   c
```

(read: `d` is the first child of `b`, `c` is the sibling of `a`).

Note that you can encode any rooted forest (with ordered components, otherwise the representation is not unique) by assigning a sibling to the root, so this

```
  a
 / \
b   c
 \   \
  d   e
```

would be read as

```
  a   c e
 / \
b   d
```

---

here is *another* method to get a unique *general (undirected) tree* from a binary tree:

- a vertex binary tree may have 0...3 graph neighbors.
- append 12 nodes to the root
- append 8 nodes to each left child
- append 4 nodes to each right child

this operation is reversible:

- label the node with at least 12 neighbors "root". If not unique, fail.
- label each node with 8..11 neighbors "left".
- label each node with 4..7 neighbors "right".
- remove all leaves
- orient all edges away from the root
- if any node has more than one left child or more than one right child, fail.

So,

- There is a bijection between ordered rooted trees and binary trees (first and second algorithm).
- Since any general tree can be arbitrarily rooted, there is a injection from general (directed or undirected) trees to binary trees.
- There is an injection from binary trees to general undirected trees (third algorithm)
- Since there is an injection from binary trees to general trees and back, there must exist a bijection between general (directed or undirected) trees and binary trees.

Comment: I don't think you answered the question. I believe the author knows that from a general tree one can construct a unique binary tree. By unique, it means reversible. And author seems understand it. The author is asking, whether we can construct a unique general tree from a binary tree.

Comment: @Haozhun this answer describes a way to construct a general *ordered rooted* tree from a binary tree. Since it is a reversal of the forwards transformation, it is itself reversible.

Comment: Why bother something this complicated if we regard general tree *ordered*? The binary tree itself will serve.

Comment: @Haozhun two distinct binary graphs may have the same child ordering: `((,),)`(left-child) `(,(,))`(right-child) are distinct but not as general trees: `(())`

Answer (score 1):

I feel unlikely. Usually, binary tree distinguishes left child and right child. However, general trees don't.

How are we supposed to get a unique general tree from these two binary tree.

```
  X      X
 / \    / \
 Y Z    Z Y
```

And how about these two?

```
  X      X
 /        \
 Y        Y
```

On the other hand,

If you choose to not distinguish left or right child of a binary tree, or choose to respect the sequence children appears in a general tree, just map each binary tree to itself. That will be a unique general tree for each binary tree.